# Python pandas dataframe convert values without decimals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

In my dataframe, I have changed the NaN to 0 with the following code

```
df5.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

However, I get the value "0.0" instead of "0". 
I have >150 columns in this dataframe, some need the decimals, and the ones with converted NaN values must be without decimals. How can I get that. 
My dataframe is for example as follows:

```
           genome  contig  genes    SCM  SCM/genes  TrfA_1__CP11611  \
source                                                                
20900_48    20900      48      1    0.0       0.00              NaN   
20900_37    20900      37    130  103.0       0.79              Nan
```

I get:

```
           genome  contig  genes    SCM  SCM/genes  TrfA_1__CP11611  \
source                                                                
20900_48    20900      48      1    0.0       0.00              0.0   
20900_37    20900      37    130  103.0       0.79              0.0
```

I need only "NaN" changed to "0" without affecting for example column SCM/genes. It is no option to use a code with columnnames, since I have >150 columns with NaN in this dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: If you have no `NaN` and all dtypes are numeric you can just do `df5 = df5.astype(int)`

Comment: have you tried using `df5.fillna(int(0), inplace=True)`?

Comment: astype(int) give the error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer / 'df5.fillna(int(0), inplace=True)' gives still the value with decimals 0.0

Comment: he meant convert to int after filling the nas - but that won't work becuase it will round your scm/genes column

Comment: take a step back... Why do you need the filled values to be 0 and the others to be 0.0? There may be straight forward solutions if we could understand the "why."

Comment: I want to write the dataframe to a csv file, and with excel, I want to set a cut-off based on the SCM/genes column (for which I need the full number, not rounded to a number without decimals) and for the other columns, I want to score 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you first filter the cols that contain `NaN`, then convert these:

```
In [26]:
nan_cols = df.columns[df.isnull().any(axis=0)]
nan_cols

Out[26]:
Index(['TrfA_1__CP11611'], dtype='object')

In [27]:
for col in nan_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(0).astype(int)
df

Out[27]:
          enome  contig  genes    SCM  SCM/genes  TrfA_1__CP11611
source                                                           
20900_48  20900      48      1    0.0       0.00                0
20900_37  20900      37    130  103.0       0.79                0
```

So this first looks for `NaN` present in any rows and makes a list of the cols, you can then iterate over the cols and call `fillna` and cast the dtype using `astype` so that you preserve/convert the dtype.